# Does the Hirsch conjecture hold for $n < 2d$?

Tags: combinatorics, linear-programming

The [Hirsch conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirsch_conjecture) states that the graph (i.e. $1$-skeleton) of a $d$-dimensional [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope) with $n$ facets has diameter at most $n - d$.

It was known for a long time that it sufficed to prove it for $n \ge 2d$ --- indeed, if $n < 2d$ then every pair of vertices shares a common facet, and iterating if necessary, one eventually ends up with a case where $N = 2D$.  (See Ziegler's book Lectures on Polytopes, p. 84).

> [Now it is known](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/articles/3941) that the Hirsch conjecture fails in general, but
>   does it hold for $n < 2d$?  So far I haven't been able to think of a
>   simple proof, and actually I don't even know if it's true.  The counterexample due to Santos has $d=43$ and $n=86$.